# Maya, Python, How do i get the name of an object based on vertex selection?

Tags: python, list, indexing, maya, vertices

I got the code working like this until i realized that the vertex index changes for geometry with over 100 vertices...

I assumed i could just split the string and everything would be dandy

```
import maya.cmds as mc
selPoints = mc.ls(sl = True) # list of names of selected vertices
objName = (str(selPoints[0]))[:-9]
print selPoints
print objName
```

Heres what it returned:

```
[u'pCylinder25.vtx[4]', u'pCylinder25.vtx[24]']
pCylinder
```

I'm trying to hack off the portion with '.vtx[integer]'

I may be going about this completely wrong, and there may be a dead simple way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be awesome if it were easy to get the object from Maya? From experience, I know it can be frustrating since MEL/maya.cmds doesn't use an object-oriented approach.

Anyhow, you should refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) often for more info on the variety of `string` methods you can use. Really comes in handy *all the time*!

To answer your question, you can use `.split` or `.find`, whichever you prefer.

```
print selPoints[0].split('.vtx')[0]
print selPoints[0][0:selPoints[0].find('.vtx')]
```

The `split` method returns a list of strings created by the delimiter string `'.vtx'`. Then, taking the first element from that list will always be the object name.

The `find` method returns the index of the substring `'.vtx'`, so the second example simply uses slicing syntax to return the correct string.

Comment: When using the find method, since your only looking for the index of the beginning of  ".vtx" , It seems to make no difference if i look for the index of "." instead.

Comment: @AsaphKim That's true and as a bonus it should always work given that object names can never contain any "." characters, so it's necessarily giving you the right index each time. However, whether you prefer to do it like that or use ".vtx" is more a question of preference. I find that it adds a bit of clarity to use 'vtx', but then again anyone familiar with Maya would also understand that the name always comes before the ".".

Answer (score 4):

You can get the object from any valid selection string with the -o flag:

```
cmds.ls("pCube1.vtx[0]", o=True)
# pCubeShape1
```

Note that will be the shape, not the transform -- that's Maya being pedantic but it is correct.  The transform would be

```
cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls("pCube1.vtx[0]", o=True), p=True)
```

You may also find it helpful to split the components using `partition`:

```
object, _, component = "pCube1.vtx[0]".partition(".")
```

where the `_` is python slang for 'ignore me'.

Answer (score 0):

just for stuff, using vanilla maya commands:

- as mentioned with `ls`:

```
cm.ls("pCube1.vtx[0]", o=1)  # will return shape pCubeShape1
```

- with `plugNode` (opposite `plugAttr`):

```
cm.plugNode("pCube1.vtx[0]")  # will return transform pCube1
```